# Propety of object is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im trying to feed in an array of objects (merchants) into a function, run through each 'merchant' and do something with the 'merchant_aw_id' of that merchant but I am getting undefined.

```
module.exports = function(merchants) {
  merchants.forEach(function eachMerchant(merchant) {
    console.log(merchant);
    }
  )
};
```

I can console.log merchant and it will return:

```
{ _id: 5596da54e4b05a4f29699441,
  merchant_id: '0001',
  merchant_aw_id: '6130',
  merchants: [] }
```

But when i do the following I get undefined:

```
module.exports = function(merchants) {
  merchants.forEach(function eachMerchant(merchant) {
    console.log(merchant.merchant_aw_id);
    }
  )
};
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the `typeof merchant` variable is a `String` which has no property `merchant_aw_id`.

Convert it to an object first:

```
module.exports = function(merchants) {
  merchants.forEach(function eachMerchant(merchant) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(merchant);
    console.log(obj.merchant_aw_id);
  });
};
```

---

Comment: Thanks - Just for others reference, I also had to do JSON.stringify() e.g. var oMerchant = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sMerchant));